# Using Highchart for two panes candlesticks and column in R

Tags: r, shiny, highcharts

I'm working with financial data and i want to reproduce same column plot with two colors in to panes one for UP (green) and red for the down ones.

Below is my code.

```r
library(highcharter)
library(quantmod)
#Retrieve stock data to plot. 
aap1<-quantmod::getSymbols("AAPL",
                           src = "yahoo",
                           from = "2020-01-01",
                           auto.assign = FALSE)



colnames(aap1)<- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted")
highchart (type="stock") %>% 
  hc_title(text = paste0("AAPL chart : from 2020-01-01 to ", Sys.Date())) %>%
  hc_add_series (name = "Prices", aap1, yAxis = 0, showInLegend = FALSE) %>%
  hc_add_yAxis (nid = 1L,  
                title = list(
                  style=list(color='#333333',
                             fontSize = "20px",
                             fontFamily= "Erica One"),
                  text = "Volume"), relative = 1)%>%
  hc_add_series (name = "Volume", aap1[, "Volume"], yAxis = 1, type="column", showInLegend= FALSE, color="red")%>%
  hc_add_yAxis (nid = 2L, 
                title = list(
                  style=list(color='#333333',
                             fontSize = "20px",
                             fontFamily= "Erica One"),
                  text = "Volume"), relative = 1)%>%
  hc_exporting(
    enabled = TRUE, # always enabled,
    filename = paste0("AAPL chart : from 2020-01-01 to ", Sys.Date())
  )
```

[This picture shows what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Emyu2.jpg)

but what I'm expecting should look like this

[green for UP and red for down for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzoxb.jpg)

All the code I'm finding are not what I'm looking for and they are also in JS and I don't know how to exactly deal with it (turn them in R code).

Comment: Seems that your first series is a `candlestick` type meanwhile you want to display an `area`. https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.area